# AI Script to control the anchor of the rectangle from the left

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting, javascript

Can I control a rectangle's anchor on the left with a script up or down (like in the picture).

```
var Rctngl=0;
var var_Integer;
mm = 2.834645731787465
var_Integer =Rctngl;
var_Integer = prompt ("Rectangle ?", var_Integer);
{  Rctngl = Math.floor (var_Integer)*mm }
app.activeDocument.defaultStroke = true;
app.activeDocument.defaultStrokeWidth = 4;
app.activeDocument.defaultFilled = false;
var box = app.activeDocument.layers[0].groupItems.add()
box.pathItems.rectangle (0, 0,  Rctngl*2, Rctngl*2);
```

[image]

Comment: Sure, but why bother? Anyway theres not really enough context here to sufgest anything useful.

Comment: sorry i added my code

Comment: Probably better to use `setEntirePath` instead of rectangle

Comment: I don't particularly want to use setEntirePath. Can only the anchors of the Rectangle be intervened?

Comment: sure but its just unnecessarily many lines of code. Why write 6 extra lines of code and take a performance hit of doing the same thing 3 times?

Comment: I am quite a beginner at script. setEntirePath sounds very confusing to me. Anchors must be combined. Your rectangle is enough for me. I guess the anchors of a rectangle cannot be controlled. Otherwise, you would give the answer right away, joojaa. Because you're so good. I'm following you.

Comment: They can be controlled just that if set entire path is confusing to you then fetching the selection and move is how would i say... Insanity. But also it teaches you nothing worthwhile doing.

Comment: If not, why did this issue prolong?  I did not understand.  You would of course not have a rectangle.  I've been ridiculed.  Don't be sorry.

Comment: You were presenting something that was clearly a XY problem. After interrogation its still a XY problem, just for no particular reason. Since answering under these circumstances is not going to satisfactory I will refrain from answering untill its nolonger a XY problem. Its fine if you want to obscure your actions but the downside is you might not get an answer.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I frantically wondered if the anchors of a rectangle could be controlled. So how do I make a script with the points combined as in the picture.

Comment: The reason im hesitant to show this for you is its not generalizable. So if i do it to a square, it does not help you do with any other shape. Only the square you made, which clearly is a job for `setEntirePath` instead, since its less work. Identifying the individual point in a arbitrary situation that the user supplies is impossible to describe, since the strategy depends on what you do. So if the example is just that a example, not your actual problem then you will not be any closer to solving your real problem. Use `setEntirePath` or describe your actual situation.